# Algorithm: optimally distribute N people among M tasks given P preferences

Tags: algorithm

**Example:** 10 candidates each give 2 preferences (the first being more preferred than the second) for 3 available jobs, and their boss must then optimally allocate *(and evenly distribute)* them **evenly** based on their preferences. Obviously, unwanted jobs will require some random draw.

How would I write an algorithm that calculates this **optimal** allocation automatically?

I looked around and found [bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) which might give me some clues, however I am having trouble wrapping my head around it!

For the "luck" aspect of the game, I already implemented a simple Fisher Yates Shuffle.

**Preference weight:**
If there are 2 preferences, when assigned to a worker, obtaining a first choice weighs +2, a second choice +1, an unwanted choice -1 (for example). The "optimality" goal is to maximize the aggregate preferences.

Comment: Are all preferences of equal weight?

Comment: there is a first choice, and a second choice, and so on. The first choice should weigh more than the second, but I guess the amount can be arbitrary?

Comment: How to you define optimal? There may not be an "optimal allocation"; see: voting paradox.

Comment: One of the combinations that has the least amount of unhappy workers. There may be several, I am aware! :) I'll add some more info to explain better:

Comment: How big are N, M and P? Exhaustive search may be feasible here.

Comment: This sounds like a [constraint problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization), in particular a soft constrained optimisation problem.

Comment: As @SimeonVisser says, the most obvious and easy-to-implement approach to this would be a brute force algorithm that tests all possible allocations of workers to tasks. Is that feasible given the numbers you're dealing with, or do you need more efficiency?

Comment: Bipartite matching can be reduced from max flow, have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934859/assigning-jobs-to-people-using-maximum-flow-harder-version

Comment: Isn't this very similar to stable marriage problems?

Comment: @nlucaroni There is a planner's problem and the standard notion of stability doesn't apply (since there are only "preferences" on one side).

Comment: This is a popular question recently. The third or fourth I've seen in the last few days. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18967396/56778

Comment: @Frank, yes that's the difference. Thanks.

Comment: What does "evenly distribute" mean?  Are you saying that each job can be done by multiple people?  That is must we end with all 10 people having one of the 3 jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite challenging, but i found a working (maybe not the most performant) solution. My Example is written in PHP, but you should be able to adapt it. I'll try to explain the "thoughts" behind the code.

**Note:** It seems like you added the "10 persons, 3 Jobs" constraint later - or i simple did overread it. However, my code should give you an example that you *might* be able to adapt to that constraint. My Code currently is assuming that there are `n` jobs for `n` persons. (The most easiest way of adapting it to the 10/3 criteria, would be to split up the 3 Jobs into 10 equal units of work, when assuming 10 workers!)

**First**, lets create some basic architecture stuff. We need `person`, `job` and obviously a matrix, representing the satisfaction of a person towards a job. The following snipped does exactly that:

```
<?php
class Person{
  var $name;
  var $prim;
  var $sec;

  function __construct($name, $prim, $sec){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->prim = $prim;
    $this->sec = $sec;
  }

  function likes($job){
    if ($job->type == $this->prim) return 2;
    if ($job->type == $this->sec) return 1;
    else return -1;
  }
}

class Job{
  var $name;
  var $type;

  function __construct($name, $type){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->type = $type;
  }
}


$persons = array(
  "Max" => new Person("Max", "programing", "testing"),
  "Peter" => new Person("Peter", "testing", "docu"),
  "Sam" => new Person("Sam", "designing", "testing")
);

$jobs = array(
  "New Classes" => new Job("New Classes", "programing"),
  "Theme change" => new Job("Theme change", "designing"),
  "Test Controller" => new Job("Test Controller", "testing")
);


// debug: draw it: 
echo "<h2>Happines with Jobs</h2> ";
echo "<table border=1>";
$p=0;
echo "<tr>";       
foreach ($jobs AS $job){
  $j=0;
  foreach ($persons as $person){
    if ($p++==0){
      echo "<tr><td></td>";
      foreach ($persons as $per) {
        echo "<td>".$per->name."</td>";
      }                             
      echo "</tr>";
    }


    if ($j++==0){
      echo "<td>".$job->name."</td>";
    }

    echo "<td>".$person->likes($job)."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This will give you a table like this:

[image: Happiness with Jobs]

**Second**, we need to create ALL permutations of jobs and persons. (actually we don't need to, but doing so, will show you the reason, why we don't need to!)

To create all permutations, we are using just the **name** of a person or job. (we can resolve the name back to the actual object later)

```
//build up all permutations
$personNames = array();
foreach ($persons AS $person){
  $personNames[] = $person->name;
}

$jobNames = array();
foreach ($jobs AS $job){
  $jobNames[] = $job->name;
}              

$personsPerms = array();
pc_permute($personNames,$personsPerms);

$jobsPerms = array();
pc_permute($jobNames,$jobsPerms);     

function pc_permute($items, &$result, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) { 
      $result[] = join('/', $perms);
    }  else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems,$result, $newperms);
         }
    }
}
```

Now, we have 2 Arrays: All job permutations and all person permutations.
For the Example given above, the arrays will look like this (3 Elements each, makes 3*2*1=6 Permutations per Array):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Max/Peter/Sam
    [1] => Peter/Max/Sam
    [2] => Max/Sam/Peter
    [3] => Sam/Max/Peter
    [4] => Peter/Sam/Max
    [5] => Sam/Peter/Max
)
Array
(
    [0] => New Classes/Theme change/Test Controller
    [1] => Theme change/New Classes/Test Controller
    [2] => New Classes/Test Controller/Theme change
    [3] => Test Controller/New Classes/Theme change
    [4] => Theme change/Test Controller/New Classes
    [5] => Test Controller/Theme change/New Classes
)
```

Now, We can create a `nXn` Table, containing ALL Values of the overall satisfaction for ALL possible job allocations:

```
// debug: draw it:            
echo "<h2>Total Happines of Combination (full join)</h2> ";
echo "<table border=1>";
$p=0;
echo "<tr>";
$row = 0;
$calculated = array();       
foreach ($jobsPerms AS $jobComb){
  $j=0;
  $jobs_t = explode("/", $jobComb);
  foreach ($personsPerms as $personComb){

    if ($p++==0){
      echo "<tr><td></td>";
      foreach ($personsPerms as $n) {
        echo "<td>".$n."</td>";
      }                             
      echo "</tr>";
    }


    if ($j++==0){
      echo "<td>".$jobComb."</td>";
    }

    $persons_t = explode("/", $personComb);
    $h = 0;


    echo "<td>";
    for ($i=0; $i< count($persons_t); $i++){      
      $h += $persons[$persons_t[$i]]->likes($jobs[$jobs_t[$i]]);
    }
    echo $h;
    echo "</td>";

  }
  $col=0;
  $row++;
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

[image]

Lets call this matrix "M"

This Matrix contains a "lot" of double combinations: (a/b) TO (1/2) is equal to (b/a) to (2/1) etc...

After all: We simple can ignore:

- Either Each row > 1
- OR Each column > 1

Ignoring all Columns > 1:

```
echo "<h2>Total Happines of Combination (ignoring columns)</h2> ";
echo "<table border=1>";
$p=0;
echo "<tr>";
$row = 0;
$calculated = array();       
foreach ($jobsPerms AS $jobComb){
  $j=0;
  $jobs_t = explode("/", $jobComb);
  $col = 0;
  $personComb = $personsPerms[0];

  if ($p++==0){
    echo "<tr><td></td>";
    echo "<td>".$personsPerms[0]."</td>";        
    echo "</tr>";
  }


  if ($j++==0){
    echo "<td>".$jobComb."</td>";
  }

  $persons_t = explode("/", $personComb);
  $h = 0;


  echo "<td>";
  for ($i=0; $i< count($persons_t); $i++){      
    $h += $persons[$persons_t[$i]]->likes($jobs[$jobs_t[$i]]);
  }
  echo $h;
  echo "</td>";

  $col=0;
  $row++;
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Output:

[image]

And there you go! In this Example (one of) the most satisfying Solution would be:

- Max -> New Classes (+2)
- Peter -> Test Controller (+2)
- Sam -> Theme Change (+2)

-> Happiness: 6.

There are other, equal distributions as well.

Example: 6 persons / 6 jobs:

```
$persons = array(
  "Max" => new Person("Max", "programing", "testing"),
  "Peter" => new Person("Peter", "testing", "docu"),
  "Sam" => new Person("Sam", "designing", "testing"),
  "Jeff" => new Person("Jeff", "docu", "programing"),
  "Fred" => new Person("Fred", "programing", "designing"),
  "Daniel" => new Person("Daniel", "designing", "docu") 
);

$jobs = array(
  "New Classes" => new Job("New Classes", "programing"),
  "Theme change" => new Job("Theme change", "designing"),
  "Test Controller" => new Job("Test Controller", "testing"),
  "Create Manual" => new Job("Create Manual", "docu"),
  "Program more!" => new Job("Program more!", "programing"),
  "Style the frontend" => new Job("Style the frontend", "designing")
);
```

[image]

results in (Persons: Max / Peter / Sam / Jeff / Fred / Daniel)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So in case of N workers and M jobs, where M > N, you suggest subdividing M. What if this is not always the case, and workers should just be as evenly distributed as possible? (in the case of 10/3, one worker will be the 4th in a group. This odd one out should be chosen solely based on his first preference, as he has the liberty to go in whatever group)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "evenly distribute" you mean you know how many people must be assigned to each project, this is the [weighted matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) *(aka "maximum cardinality bipartite matching")*.  Just treat each open position (rather than each job) as a node - so, a job with 3 positions will have three nodes.

The wikipedia article gives several solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudocode

```
for(n to number of jobs left)
{
  job n = a random candidate
  if(random candidate first preference == job n)
    remove random candidate from list and remove job from list
}

if(jobs left)
{
  for(n to number of jobs left)
    for(i to number of candidates)
      if(candidate first preference == job n)
      {
          job n = candidate i
          remove candidate i from list and remove job n from list
      }
      else if(candidate second preference == job n)
      {
          job n = candidate i
      }
}
```

Comment: Even without reading the code in detail, removing candidates and jobs from the list here as soon as you've matched a candidate with their first preference job is obviously wrong, because there are easy-to-construct cases in which the optimal solution involves some candidate(s) not getting their first preference.

Comment: You probably should have read the code in more detail as a job and candidate is only removed when its matched with their first preference.
The first bit just fills all the jobs and sometimes will get lucky matching first preference. ie so all jobs get a candidate